# Pentaho Report with Python Script

Tags: pentaho

I am using query for generating report in pentaho report designer, But query has some limitation so,

Any possibility in Pentaho Report Designer we can generate output base on python script?

Comment: What precisely do you mean? You want to use Python as a datasource? Or use python to script execution of Pentaho reports?  Or something else?

Comment: we can report report based on java, but not sure python script will work or not

Answer (score 0):

As of 8-2011, there was no support of Python scripting in Pentaho. One of the forum threads from that time discusses the lack of support on the Pentaho dev side for Python [here](http://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?83447-How-to-run-a-Python-script-in-Experimental-Script-step).

There is also an [earlier thread](http://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?76999-Python-and-Kettle-4-0-0-RC1) regarding using jython to supplant interpreter-style scripting.

I don't know if there has been any integration since then. The forum thread above talks about a Ruby-based workaround (which I have not been able to successfully execute).

If you figure it out, please let me know! I would love to bring numpy to my Pentaho reports.

Answer (score 0):

I've embedded the jython library in the libext path of the report designer. Then, I defined a BSF datasource, imported the library and executed a python script from there directly from java, it worked as a charm!.

I think, a function with BSF (Bean Scripting Framework) could do the same if you need to call python script from java while processing the rows.

I haven't fully tested BSF capabilities of PDI, but I think you can achieve the same goal in similar way (maybe in the BSF step, execute java code, and inside the java code, the execution of python via jython).

But, after all, if you can use a full object-oriented language like java via BSF, why to use python?